# Unable to add/remove disabled attribute in button based on checkbox checked property

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function  enableDisableButton() {

    var isChecked = ($('input[name=ignore-checkbox]').is(':checked'));

    if (isChecked == true) {
        $("button[name=set-up-account]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("button[name=set-up-account]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

}

$('#mobilePage').live('pageinit', function (event) {    //document ready for jquery mobile

    enableDisableButton();

    $('#ignore-checkbox').bind("change", function () {
        enableDisableButton();
    });

});
  </script>
```

Html:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Account", "SetUpAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "account-set-up", @data_ajax = "false" }))
 {       

     <div class="ui-grid-a field">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:140px;">
         <label for="ignore-checkbox">Ignore</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="ignore-checkbox" id="ignore-checkbox"/>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
         <button type="submit" name="set-up-account" id="set-up-account"  data-inline="true"  data-mini="true">Set Up Account</button>
     </div>
  }
```

I want to enable/disable the `Set Up Account` button based on check box checked property. If checkbox is checked, then enable the button, else disable. On page load i am disabling the button

The problem i am facing is,

On page load, its disabling the button, but its not adding/removing the disabled attribute based on change event of check box, i checked in firebug, its entering the loop properly based on checked and unchecked value.

Note: I am using Jquery mobile 1.2 and jquery 1.7. Also before posting here i searched in google, there are many postings under enabling and disabling of button based on checkbox checked value. but none solves my issue.

What's the problem? please help me

Thanks...

Comment: Your code works fine see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwzGf/2/ `:)` click on the checkbox and you will see the enabling and disabling, of button

Comment: But in my page its not removing the disabled attribute on checking the check box, its may be because of jquery mobile?

Comment: Try this - minor change: http://jsfiddle.net/26n4M/1/ instead of `(isChecked == true)` just do `(isChecked)` , it should work in JQ M `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit Ya, now its enabling the button on checking the check box, but its not disabling if ischecked is false

Comment: Working here **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KGvve/ `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit Thanks for your help, but in my page its not disabling back

Comment: hmm can you create a demo for me please, seems like the one I created for you is working `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not enabling the button because of Jquery Mobile. In JQM, we need to refresh the form element, while manipulating it

The solution is

```
    function  enableDisableButton() {

    var isChecked = ($('input[name=ignore-checkbox]').is(':checked'));

    if (isChecked) {
        $("button[name='set-up-account']").removeAttr("disabled").button('refresh');
    }
    else {
        $("button[name='set-up-account']").attr("disabled", "disabled").button('refresh');
   }
}

$('#mobilePage').live('pageinit', function (event) {

    enableDisableButton();

    $('#ignore-checkbox').bind("change", function () {
        enableDisableButton();
    });
});
```

The problem was solved by adding

```
.button('refresh');
```

Answer (score 45):

I'm not sure if this will help solve your main problem, but according to http://api.jquery.com/prop/ you should be adding and removing the disabled property using the .prop() function, not the .attr() and .removeAttr() functions.

To add the property:

```
.prop("disabled", true);
```

To remove the property:

```
.prop("disabled", false);
```

I stumbled across this question while looking for the above info, so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 7):

Like this one

```
  $('#setagb').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#submit").attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
        }               
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name=ignore-checkbox]").click(function() {
  $("button[name=set-up-account]").attr("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/26n4M/3/)

Comment: Yes tried, its firing the click event, but not enabling the button

Comment: Have you checked the demo? Its enabling and disabling button when you checked or unchecked the checkbox

Comment: This is one of the solution. Now its up to you to modify it according to your need to make it work.