# Jquery work in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox

I would like to create a checkbox, and when the checkbox is checked, the button btnAccept wil change its css class and become d

My code is working fine Firefox, but it wont work in Google Chrome. I try to google about whole day still cant find the solution, anyone know what is my mistake? My code is as below:
This is Jquery code :

```
function checkboxclick() {
    $("input[id*='TermAcceptCheckBox']").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").addClass("blue-button19");
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").removeClass("blue-button19");
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
```

This is html code:
`<asp:CheckBox ID="TermAcceptCheckBox" runat="server" visible="True" OnChange="javascript:checkboxclick();"/>`

Comment: try to debug exactly which part is not working for u.Than it become easy for u

Comment: are you always format your code in same way as you posted here .. It is not readable at all. please format your jquery code .

Comment: @rahularyansharma better now, after my edit? It was lost in markdown

Comment: Try with `prop` instead of `attr`. `attr` only sets the default value since jQuery ~1.7

Comment: Why do you use this: `$("input[id*='TermAcceptCheckBox']")` and not `$("#TermAcceptCheckBox")`? Using ID's requires the use of _unique_ identifiers thus using the JQuery Attribute Contains selector is useless here.

Comment: @DaanTimmer But he's using each, maybe he's got many `TermAcceptCheckboxes` ? But yes it's weird, think using classes instead of an ID...

Comment: @soyuka then he shouldn't be using ID's? Else it is invalid HTML anyway and I wouldn't mind saying "your code is not working because it is invalid HTML" -fix that first.

Comment: @DaanTimmer Why not, but if he has duplicated ID (`each`) he should not, should he ? See my edit.

@Panadol Chong : did you have multiple checkboxes ?

Comment: Hello guys, Sorry for late reply, very busy this few days. I already found the solution. The problem is, I should used OnClick="javascript:checkboxclick();" instead of OnChange="javascript:checkboxclick();", after I change to OnClick, it is solved. : ) THanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
if (this.checked) {
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").addClass("blue-button19");
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").removeClass("blue-button19");
            $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like that with jQuery :

```
$("input[id*='TermAcceptCheckBox']").each(function () {
    $btnToDisable = $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>");

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $btnToDisable.removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $btnToDisable.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $btnToDisable.toggleClass("blue-button19");

});
```

I did a much easier example :

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />

<button id="btn" disabled="disabled">My Button</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#myCheckbox').on('click', function() {
    $btnToDisable = $("#btn");

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $btnToDisable.removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $btnToDisable.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $btnToDisable.toggleClass("blue-button19");

});
```

See it [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/4rb6w/).

So the problem could be from :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="TermAcceptCheckBox" runat="server" visible="True" OnChange="javascript:checkboxclick();"/>
```

Change `OnChange` by `OnClick` :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="TermAcceptCheckBox" runat="server" visible="True" OnClick="javascript:checkboxclick();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to disable and enable the button:

```
$("button[name='set-up-account']").removeAttr("disabled");
```

and

```
("button[name='set-up-account']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and according to your code it should be:

```
function checkboxclick() {
$("input[id*='TermAcceptCheckBox']").each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").addClass("blue-button19");
        $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").removeClass("blue-button19");
        $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

}

try this hope it will resolve your problem

Comment: What is .button(..) doing?

Comment: @mplungjan by mistake that added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266246/unable-to-add-remove-disabled-attribute-in-button-based-on-checkbox-checked-prop    please review the accepted answer..

Answer (score 0):

**Important**: Use CLICK and not CHANGE since change needs a blur.

I assume you only have one checkbox, so no need for each.
Also I use prop instead of attr and chain the calls, so much simpler jQuery

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Wj7Ft/)**

```
<asp:CheckBox id="TermAcceptCheckBox" runat="server" visible="True" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#<%=TermAcceptCheckBox.ClientID%>").on("click", function() {
    var button = $("#<%=btnAccept.ClientID%>");
    var chk = $(this).is(":checked");
    button.prop("disabled", !chk).toggleClass("blue-button19",chk);
  });
})
```

---

Please note that it is a good idea to put the test in a function and call it onload too in case the user reloads the page

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xE5EB/)**

```
function acceptCheck(checkbox,button) {
    var chk = checkbox.is(":checked");
    button.prop("disabled", !chk).toggleClass("blue-button19",chk);    
}
$(function() {
  $("#TermAcceptCheckBox").on("click", function() {
    acceptCheck($(this), $("#btnAccept"));
  });
  acceptCheck($("#TermAcceptCheckBox"), $("#btnAccept"));
})
```